# React light/dark mode toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to build the simplest dark/light toggler button in react, there is. So far I have made a toggler component and gave it a state with

```
this.state = {style: './App.css'}
```

and 2 functions one is setting the this.state.style to `./darkmode.css` the other one is back to `./App.css` I binded them to 2 buttons. My question is, is there any way for using something like this: import 'this.state.style' instead of the import `./App.css` in the App.js file? At least my way of thinking got me here, as this looked to be the easiest to do in order to change the stylesheet of the page. There is no big deal in the css files only smooth camera and bg color.

Comment: The state would be used to load CSS into the header of your page based on light or dark

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that, but on the JS side you can change the class of the body element when pressing the button with .TogggleClass(). On the CSS side you just change the css.

Answer (score 1):

the most suitable solution for making simple dark / light mode is by using Context API and `useContext` Hook it is easier, simpler and more readable than using any other solutions, you can make a whole new themes with this solution. so give it a try and you will definitely enjoy with the result and the experiment.